# Waterfall Rock Hit Counter

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm having a difficulity in solving a problem from my class, it's about dynamic programming (or so my professor called it). The problem is called Waterfall Rock Hit. (Time limit : 1s, Memory Limit : 16mb)

We're given the upper left (v1, h1) and lower right coordinate (v2, h2) of the rock and we simulate a waterfall and count number of rock hit by the water, imagine the water started falling from a coordinate (x,y), it will fall to (x-1, y) and continue to fall until it hit a rock. when it hit a rock, the water will split to the right and left, and follow the length of the rock, here's the a picture of how the algorithm will work.
[Simulation Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOdDX.png).

What we need to watch here, if the rock was hit more than once, the problem also guaranteed there won't any rock stick to each other, and the water will always find a way through any 2 rocks.

Here's a piece of my incomplete code, where i still thinking of the second condition for when the water hit the rock and preventing double count.

```
int maks=0, n, m, nstone;
struct a{
   int v1, v2, h1, h2; //coordinates
   bool pass; //passed or not?
}; a arr[5000];

bool acompare(a lhs, a rhs){
   return  lhs.v1 < rhs.v1; //compare height descending
}

int fall(int x, int y){
   if (x == n || y == m || y == -1) //if the water passed the wall
      return 0;
   else if () //the confusing condition if the water hit the rock
      return 1 + fall(x, h1-1) + fall(x, h2+1));
   else // if there's nothing below
      return fall(x-1, y);
}

int main(){
   cin>> n>> m>> nstone; //waterfall size (n*m) and number of stone
   for (int i=0; i<nstone; i++){ //read the stone's corner
      cin>> arr[i].v1>> arr[i].h1>> arr[i].v2>> arr[i].h2; 
      arr[i].pass = false;
   }

   sort(arr, arr+nstone, acompare); //sort the stone's based on height
   cin>> start; //read the start point of the water
   cout<< fall(start, m)<< endl;

   return 0;
}
```

---

testcase sample input :

```
6 6 3  
2 3 2 4  
4 2 5 2  
5 5 6 5
```

output :

```
3
```

Comment: I don't see how is this DP, this is just recursion.

Comment: @user202729 yes, i can understand your point, however when i talked that to my professor, he insisted that this problem is a DP but i will keep it mind and add the recursion tags to this question

Comment: Is there any time restriction? Surely you don't want too inefficient code right?

Comment: And add [tag:c++] too.

Comment: @user202729 yes, there is time restriction of 1s and memory limit of 16 mb, thank you for reminding me that

Comment: It's still not clear enough. Obviously you can't solve the problem with 10¹² rocks in 1 second. What's the limit on the input?

Comment: @user202729 maximum input is 500 for every number (grid size 500*500, number of rock 500, etc)

Comment: Then... I think letting you do the runtime analysis yourself would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the condition you have trouble with. It's inefficient to iterate all rocks on each step, even binary search is not optimal. This can be solved by a table, like in a board game. Create a NxM 2D array for this (e.g. 4 bytes each item = 250000 * 4 bytes = 2MB, far away from your 16MB limit) and mark all points covered by rocks. On each step you'll need to check a single point if it's a rock.

Secondly, it's a DP problem because streams can merge like the one in the bottom middle:

```
..|..
.|X|.
.|.|.
|X|X|
|.|.|
```

Your approach would calculate this stream twice. (BTW, I don't see where you use your `bool pass; //passed or not?` member) Once calculated store the number of rocks the stream has hit in your board game table, e.g. in your example:

```
.1331.
.1XX1.
010.1.
0X0010
0X00X0
0.00X0
```

So next time you reach already calculated point of a stream you already know how many rocks you hit from this point.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you don't use `std::vector` and use C-style array instead. I would assume that you're not familiar with C++ STL library and hence will provide an answer that uses as little of C++ STL as possible.

---

Because there are multiple stones to check, you need to use a loop (or `std::find_if`) to check all of them.

```
for(int stone_index=0;stone_index<nstone;++stone_index)
```

For each stone, check if the `(x,y)` coordinate is right on the top of that stone.

Once you've found one, it's guaranteed that you won't found any other ones (because stones don't touch), so just return immediately.

```
return 1 + fall(x, h1-1) + fall(x, h2+1));
```

(this is just pseudocode, replace `h1` and `h2` with suitable values)

If you reach the end of the loop without finding a stone,

```
// if there's nothing below
return fall(x-1, y);
```

---

Note that this solution requires `nstone` steps to check, you can do better using a `std::map` or something. That may be too hard for you.

Comment: i understand that idea, to be honest, that was my first idea in solving this problem, but can it be done under 1s?